# Using HQL exclude parents that have a child with a specific value

Tags: hql, parent-child

I have some tables with a relationship like

```
  Parent
 ------
 parentPk
 //data

 Child
 ------
 parentFk
 status
 //data
```

I want to retrieve all the parents *without* a child in a specific status. Now, I could do this with a "not in" clause like

```
 ... where parentPk not in (select parentFk from Child where status="ABC")
```

However, this seems inefficient. What I'd really like to do is something like

```
 where "ABC" not in elements(Parent.child.status)
```

but obviously that doesn't work because status is not a collection. Is there a way to make it do what I want or is the "not in" clause my best bet?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using

```
 where "ABC" not in (select child.status from Child as child where child.parentFk = parent.parentPk)
```

Still not ideal, but better than retrieving all keys